# Ιn which "Star Trek: The Next Generation" episode does Picard demand arbitration by a hibernating species?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I remember in one of the episodes Picard has a trouble due to violation of some treaty with another species. After analysing the contents of the treaty he finds out that he can demand a 3rd-party species to arbitrate.

The other species agrees and he (cleverly) says that he wants arbitrator from a species who hibernates for 6 months of the year.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That would be ["The Ensigns of Command"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Ensigns_of_Command_(episode)) (S03E02, 1989), the "some species" would be the [Sheliak](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sheliak), and Picard's proposed mediators were the [Grizzelas](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Grizzela) (who happened to be hibernating at the time and wouldn't awaken for six months).

Comment: awesome ! Thanks a lot, just completed watching that episode after you told bat that :)